# Vue - Transitioning the route doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue 3 with vue router, and I used the same code from the docs for transitioning the route, and it worked at first, but after some changes in the code in other files, it decided not to work ;-;

Here is my app.vue

```
<template>
  <Nav />
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="Fade">
      <div>
        <component :is="Component" />
      </div>
    </transition>
  </router-view>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from "@/components/Nav.vue";

export default {
  name: "HomeView",
  components: {
    Nav,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.Fade-enter-from,
.Fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(120px);
}
.Fade-enter-active,
.Fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
</style>
```

and here's the Main Route

```
<template>
  <div>
    <WText />
    <Softwares />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import WText from "@/components/WText.vue";
import Softwares from "@/components/Softwares.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    WText,
    Softwares,
  },
};
</script>
```

The other route (contact) is just an empty vue file, nothing special.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: The transition behaves like it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

transition tag works when inner content re-renders (which could mean `Component` variable change, setting `v-if="true"` to `v-if="false"` and viceversa.), wrapping `<component>` tag with `div` will keep a constant dom element existing. Getting rid of wrapper `div` (or force rerender when `Component` variable changes which is not a good way to do it.)